# globalPackagesFolder repositoryPath difference

Tags: nuget

According to [`globalPackagesFolder` NuGet Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section), it allows you to change the location of the default global packages folder instead of Users{username}.nuget\packages. So, I figure out it's where packages are stored.

By other hand, [`repositoryPath` NuGet Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section), it allows you to install the NuGet packages in the specified folder.

I don't understand what this documentation is treating to say.

Could anybody exaplin me which's each one for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The globalPackagesFolder is a global cache of NuGet packages. This is where NuGet downloads NuGet packages to as a machine cache. NuGet may clean out the cache when too many packages are stored here.

The repositoryPath is the packages directory a solution will use, when using a packages.config file. It is usually a path relative to the solution. It can however be a global folder on your machine but typically it would not be the same as NuGet's global machine cache.

Comment: the `repositoryPath` only applies to the `packages.config` format. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file

Answer (score 3):

As it stands today, it seems the two settings do the same, but `globalPackagesFolder` has to be used for projects using `PackageReference`, `repositoryPath` is for projects using `packages.config`.