# How can I change the path for packages with nuget in VS2015 for a specific solution in the new json format?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I've created a new C# Blank App using VS2015 update 3. I wish to change the directory for the packages. This was used to be in the nuget.config file, but now, it is a packages.json for newly created projects. I'm looking for something like reprositoryPath which has worked in packages.config but now, we have a project.json to work with.

I tried to update via

```
nuget config -set repositoryPath=c:\packages -ConfigFile <path>\project.json
```

but I got the

> config: invalid arguments.

message. I've found this other thread: [globalPackagesFolder repositoryPath difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915589/globalpackagesfolder-repositorypath-difference)

but globalPackagesFolder is not solution-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a `NuGet.Config` file next to your solution to specify both `repositoryPath` and `globalPackagesFolder` for all projects in the directory hierarchy at or below the file. However, project.json based projects do not use a local repository, only the global folder.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change the path for packages with nuget in VS2015 for a specific solution in the new json format?

Just as Martin mentioned that:

packages.config uses **repositoryPath**

project.json uses **globalPackagesFolder**

So project.json project doesn't support repositoryPath config now, if you want to change packages default location for the project.json project, you can **set "NUGET_PACKAGES" environment variable** to do that. Just Set "NUGET_PACKAGES" = "c:\teampackages".

Besides, for the classic .Net project, you can place a Nuget.Config file in the root folder of the solution to control the repository path. If you don't want to change the location of the packages for project.json project, then you don't need to add this environment variable. The packages will be restored to the default path on you machine and the project.json project could find and use them automatically.

For the detail information, you can refer to the [Issue 626](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/626) on GitHub