# Change nuget packages folder and use another NuGet.Config in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I want to change nuget package folder but it doesn't work.
I tried very much tricks but not work.
I restart many times VS but not work.

My config:

- Visual Studio Community 2019
- Windows 10 1909 x64

I have a VS solution folder

- MyProjectSln\

  - HelloWorld\

    - bin
    - nuget_packages
    - NuGet.Config

I want VS studio nuget package manager console use the "NuGet.Config" file and put all packages downloaded in "nuget_packages"

So nuget packages must be in D:\MyProjetSln\HelloWorld\nuget_packages.

Content example of D:\MyProjetSln\HelloWorld\NuGet.Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value=".\nuget_packages" />
        <!-- I have also tried with repositoryPath but not work -->
    </config>
</configuration>
```

The xml syntax is correct in my case (in my file).

Example, when i execute the command "install-package NUnit" from Package Manager Console, it put downloaded packages in D:\MyProjectSln\packages\ and I don't want that.

Thank you for helping !

Comment: Whats your use case for forcing the package location?

Comment: I just want a different structure of my project

Comment: _"The globalPackagesFolder is a global **cache** of NuGet packages. This is where NuGet downloads NuGet packages to **as a machine cache**. NuGet may clean out the cache when too many packages are stored here."_ - doesn't sound like this is what you want to use, then. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39920838/43846

Comment: Are you looking for [`RestorePackagesPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing this message, what I want is not possible at the moment.

Maybe it will be a feature later.

Answer (score 1):

**Just** as [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file) said, the new `nuget.config` file must be under the same level directory of the project folder rather than put the file inside the project folder.

**In other words**, it must be located in at least the solution directory or a higher-level directory.

**Note**: if you use this way, it will act on all the projects in the same level directory and all the projects in the sub directory.

So you should put the new `nuget.config` file on the `D:\MyProjetSln`.

Then modify its content as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
         <add key="repositoryPath" value="HelloWorld\nuget_packages" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```

Then, close VS and then reopen your project to enable that function.

**In my side,**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is "the peer directory"?

Comment: It means the same level directory.

Comment: but if you have multiple projects in the same solution folder, and you have for example the same package but with different version, how do you do ?

Ex: project HelloWorld and project HelloSun


And as the document said, we can't have nuget.config in each project , is it correct ?

Comment: As far as I know, it is impossible. In fact, `nuget.config` file is not as flexible as you think, and it cannot be positioned in every project. And the properties of msbuild cannot be recognized by `nuget.config`. And it cannot identify each project and then package nuget into the project folder. So I am afraid that you cannnot get what you want.

Comment: If you still want this feature, I suggest you could report this feature on [nuget github](https://github.com/NuGet) or on [our user voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8).